# Outlook Exchange 2010- OWA/Outlook Client issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-web-app

Would there be a obvious reason why users can access OWA to receive email but they get a disconnect error on their Outlook client?

**Things I've done**:

Restarted/Checked all Microsoft Exchange Services. No errors

Rolled back new update- Rollup 6 for Exchange 2010 SP3

Checked Event View logs

Ran Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer

Possible Solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006508

**However** Outlook Client is disconnected from Exchange 2010 SP3 Server, where OWA link works great and allows client to send and receive email
Any suggestions on what I can do to troubleshoot this further?

OS:Windows 2008 R2
Exchange 2010 SP3

Comment: Your MX record isn't going to affect how Outlook clients connect. What version of Outlook?

Comment: `1.` Your MX records don't have anything to do with email clients connecting to their mailboxes. `2.` Blacklists don't have anything to do with email clients connecting to their mailboxes. `3.` Rolling back the updates seems a bit extreme considering you don't have any idea what's causing the problem. I wouldn't roll back the updates until I was sure they were the problem. `4.` Can you give us some detail on what you mean by `they get a disconnect error on their Outlook client`? `5.` Have you tried the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer? If not, then do so and post the results back here.

Comment: What @joeqwerty said : consult this first. https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: Simple check on the client done via holding CTRL and right clicking the Outlook notification bar Icon and choosing `Connection Status` and `Test Email Autoconfiguration` to see what is happening at a quick glance?

Comment: Have been using Exchange 2010 SP3 rollup 6 just fine. Agreed with the above comments, first step use the Microsoft Connectivity test. Would also triple check Microsoft Exchange RPC Client Access service.

Comment: Edit above. Also results: http://simplecomputerblog.com/RCATestResult.html. I believe it's a RPC encryption requirment error. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006508 A SSL Certificate error?

Comment: Have you always used the wrong certificate name, as that test result shows? Try the Exchange ActiveSync test as well.

Comment: To be honest I was just put into this role. We are a small firm and the I.T Admin just left without notice.  I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the results from Microsoft's Remote Connectivity Analyzer, there is a problem with your autodiscover service, which is the service used by Outlook to automatically locate your Exchange server.

Autodiscover is a web service running on your Exchange server, and it should be published to the Internet just like OWA and all other Exchange web services (EWS, ECP, OAB, ActiveSync); an Outlook client will try to locate it using three systems:

- It will look for a web server at the URL `https://yoursmtpdomain.com` and, if one is found, it will call the web service from this site.
- If this fails, it will try the same with the URL `https://autodiscover.yoursmtpdomain.com`.
- Finally, if this fails too, it will look for a DNS SRV record called `_autodiscover._tcp.yoursmtpdomain.com` and connect to the web server pointed to by that record, whatever its actual name is.

Neither of these solutions seem to be in place in your environment, thus the autodiscover process fails, and Outlook doesn't know where it should connect to. There actually *is* a web server answering at the URL https://jonesstuckey.com, but:

1. It's not your Exchange server
2. It doesn't have a valid certificate, because the site name doesn't match the certificate name.

I took the liberty to do a quick probe to your Exchange server, which I (correctly) guessed is located at https://mail.jonesstuckey.com. The certificate you're using contains the names `mail.jonesstuckey.com` and `www.mail.jonesstuckey.com` (which looks useless), so, unless you want to replace it with another certificate containing also `autodiscover.jonesstuckey.com` (which would be the correct solution), you can only successfully use the third autodiscover method, i.e. create a DNS SRV record called `_autodiscover._tcp.jonesstuckey.com` and point it to `mail.jonesstuckey.com` on TCP port 443.

This should fix your autodiscover problem; if then your Outlook clients still can't connect, post another question and we'll see if we can help you further.

Comment: I will try this. But why would a client be able to access OWA fine, but not be connected to the Exchange Server via Outlook Client?

Comment: Because OWA is a web application running on your Exchange server, while Outlook talks to different web services (Outlook Anywhere, autodiscover, and a couple more) running on the same server but in a completely different way.

Comment: Also, you should configure the URLs for the various Exchange web services, and enable Outlook Anywhere (which is by default disabled). Have a look on MSDN. Exchange is quite a complex product, and it's *not* meant to work out-of-the-box, it *needs* proper configuration.

Comment: My solution had nothing to do with certificates .

Comment: Well, good for you. But from the data you posted, the error was in the autodiscover service not working; the Remote Connectivity Analyzer didn't even *get* to try to connect to the RPC Client Access Service, because it wasn't even able to *find* it.

Answer (score -1):

What worked was the link I provided above: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006508

I ran their resolution with no luck. In fact it mention that the resolution was not applied to the RPC Client Access. I thought to my self...hmmm...maybe check to make sure the RPC Client Access Service is running? Turns out it was disable! Enabled it and started it! Connection restored to Outlook Clients!

Comment: That service should never be disabled. Maybe stopped if it crashed for some reason (which is unlikely), but definitely not disabled...